# How can I make the navbar scroll and fix to the top of the page when it is expanded?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, affix

When my navbar is collapsed, scrolling is normal and the navbar becomes fixed to the top of the page when scrolling past the header/ jumbotron. However, when the navbar is expanded (revealing 'one', 'two', and 'three'), the page will jump skipping some of the content and covering it up by the navbar. How can I make the page scroll/ behave "normally" and allow the expanded navbar fix to the top of the page without jumping over content below?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <style>
        .affix {
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .affix + .container-fluid {
            padding-top: 70px;
        }
        nav {
            z-index: 9;
        }
        .emoji p:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#f64e09; color:#fff; height:200px;">
        <div class="container text-center" style="color: white;">
            <div>
                <h1 style="font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;">Website</h1> </div>
            <h1 style="font-size: 30px; font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;">

    </h1> </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-static-top">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button> <a id="navId" class="navbar-brand" style="color:white;" href="#">Navbar Title</a> </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">One</a> </li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Two</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Three</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Start containter for everything south of navbar -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container" style="padding-top: 20px;">
            <h1>Content so the page scrolls</h1>
            <h1>Content so the page scrolls</h1>
            <h1>Content so the page scrolls</h1>
            <h1>Content so the page scrolls</h1>
            <h1>Content so the page scrolls</h1>
            <h1>Content so the page scrolls</h1>
            <h1>Content so the page scrolls</h1>
            <h1>Content so the page scrolls</h1>
            <h1>Content so the page scrolls</h1> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="font-family: 'Cabin', sans-    serif;">
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <center>
                <p>This is the footer</p>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably know, the reason why your content is not "jumping" while navbar is collapsed is in this style:

```
.affix + .container-fluid {
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

But when you are extending navbar, padding remains the same, but navbar itself becames taller. So, we have to somehow distingush those situations.

We can add some `javascript` to add an extra class to the `<nav>` element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var navBar = $('#myNavbar');
        $('.navbar-toggle').click(function(e) {
            if (!navBar.is(':visible')) {
                // #myNavbar is about to be shown, add extra class to parent <nav>
                navBar.parents('nav').addClass('affix-visible-navbar');
            } else {
                // #myNavbar is about to be hidden, remove extra class from parent <nav>
                navBar.parents('nav').removeClass('affix-visible-navbar');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and define new css-class:

```
.affix.affix-visible-navbar + .container-fluid  {
    padding-top: 155px !important;
}
```

So the complete working solution will look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <style>
        .affix {
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .affix + .container-fluid {
            padding-top: 70px;
        }
        .affix.affix-visible-navbar + .container-fluid  {
            padding-top: 155px !important;
        }
        nav {
            z-index: 9;
        }
        .emoji p:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var navBar = $('#myNavbar');
            $('.navbar-toggle').click(function(e) {
                if (!navBar.is(':visible')) {
                    // #myNavbar is about to be shown, add extra class to parent <nav>
                    navBar.parents('nav').addClass('affix-visible-navbar');
                } else {
                    // #myNavbar is about to be hidden, remove extra class from parent <nav>
                    navBar.parents('nav').removeClass('affix-visible-navbar');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#f64e09; color:#fff; height:200px;">
        <div class="container text-center" style="color: white;">
            <div>
                <h1 style="font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;">Website</h1> </div>
            <h1 style="font-size: 30px; font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;">

    </h1> </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-static-top">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button> <a id="navId" class="navbar-brand" style="color:white;" href="#">Navbar Title</a> </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">One</a> </li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Two</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Three</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Start containter for everything south of navbar -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container" style="padding-top: 20px;">
            <h1>Content so the page scrolls</h1>
            <h1>Content so the page scrolls</h1>
            <h1>Content so the page scrolls</h1>
            <h1>Content so the page scrolls</h1>
            <h1>Content so the page scrolls</h1>
            <h1>Content so the page scrolls</h1>
            <h1>Content so the page scrolls</h1>
            <h1>Content so the page scrolls</h1>
            <h1>Content so the page scrolls</h1> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="font-family: 'Cabin', sans-    serif;">
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <center>
                <p>This is the footer</p>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Of course, if you are changing `#myNavbar` elements (e.g. add/remove items), you have to adjust padding in the `.affix.affix-visible-navbar + .container-fluid {}`

Comment: I did, but it doesn't show because I'm too new of a user.

Comment: Hey, I have a followup question about this problem still. Can you help me out?

Comment: @user3376899, sure, what question?